# How to get data from web in python using curl?

Tags: python

> In bash when I used

myscript.sh

```
file="/tmp/vipin/kk.txt" 
curl -L "myabcurlx=10&id-11.com" > $file

cat $file
```

`./myscript.sh` gives me below output

```
1,2,33abc
2,54fdd,fddg3
3,fffff,gfr54
```

> When I tried to fetch it using python and tried below code -

mypython.py

```
command = curl + ' -L ' + 'myabcurlx=10&id-11.com'
output = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().decode('ascii')
print(output)
```

`python mypython.py` throw error, Can you please point out what is wrong with my code.

Error :

```
/bin/sh: line 1: &id=11: command not found
Wrong Parameter
```

Comment: Your command line has quotes around the second argument. Your Python string does not.

Comment: Meanwhile, why are you trying to build a command line and run it with `shell=True`? Why not just build a list and run it directly? Among many other benefits, that means you don’t need to worry about getting the arguments properly quoted.

Comment: Moreover, why use an external tool such as `curl` when Python has a built-in HTTP client library (though you'll probably want to use the third-party convenience library `requests`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
command = curl + ' -L ' + 'myabcurlx=10&id-11.com'
```

Print out what this string is, or just think about it. Assuming that `curl` is the string `'curl'` or `'/usr/bin/curl'` or something, you get:

```
curl -L myabcurlx=10&id-11.com
```

That’s obviously not the same thing you typed at the shell. Most importantly, that last argument is not quoted, and it has a `&` in the middle of it, which means that what you’re actually asking it to do is to run `curl` in the background and then run some other program that doesn’t exist, as if you’d done this:

```
curl -L myabcurlx=10 &
id-11.com
```

Obviously you could manually include quotes in the string:

```
command = curl + ' -L ' + '"myabcurlx=10&id-11.com"'
```

… but that won’t work if the string is, say, a variable rather than a literal in your source—especially if that variable might have quote characters within it.

The `shlex` module has helpers to quoting things properly.

But the easiest thing to do is just not try to build a command line in the first place. You aren’t using any shell features here, so why add the extra headaches, performance costs, problems with the shell getting in the way of your output and retcode, and possible security issues for no benefit?

Make the arguments a list rather than a string:

```
command = [curl, '-L', 'myabcurlx=10&id-11.com']
```

… and leave off the `shell=True`

And it just works. No need to get spaces and quotes and escapes right.

Well, it still won’t work, because `Popen` doesn’t return output, it’s a constructor for a `Popen` object. But that’s a whole separate problem—which should be easy to solve if you read the docs.

But for this case, an even better solution is to use the Python bindings to libcurl instead of calling the command-line tool. Or, even better, since you’re not using any of the complicated features of curl in the first place, just use `requests` to make the same request. Either way, you get a response object as a Python object with useful attributes like `text` and `headers` and `request.headers` that you can’t get from a command line tool except by parsing its output as a giant string.

Comment: Probably use `run` or `check_output` rather than `Popen` though.

Comment: @tripleee Yes—either that, or he has to call `communicate`. But fixing all of the problems, even the ones he didn’t ask for, with copy-pastable code often leads to people (future readers, not just the OP) just copy-pasting and ignoring the whole last paragraph, while fixing the problem only to immediately run into another one they didn’t know to ask about might make them consider that maybe using pycurl or requests really is easier.

Answer (score -1):

```
import subprocess

fileName="/tmp/vipin/kk.txt"

with open(fileName,"w") as f:
  subprocess.read(["curl","-L","myabcurlx=10&id-11.com"],stdout=f)

print(fileName)
```

**recommended approaches:**

- https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.request.html#examples
- http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/

Comment: Giving people Python 2-specific answers when they’re using Python 3, especially novices, is a bad idea. It’s not just the `print`; you’re also recommending `urllib2`, which no longer exists, and `subprocess.call`, which is deprecated.